# Create custom page template based on default for dexterity type

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have created a page template for my custom dexterity type.
The default view automatically shows all the fields, rather than my custom template which shows no fields.

I'd like to start my template by copying the default template. I have tried pasting in a copy of plone.app.dexterity.browser/item.pt however that gives me

```
LocationError: (<my.types.resource.ResourceView object at 0xb4d18bcc>, 'widgets')
```

I am not sure why.

I guess that using this template might not even be the best solution, if I need to change the way individual fields render. In that case I am wondering how I can start with a template which contains the fields in my type (in the past I used ArchGenXML). Is there an equivalent process for dexterity?

Comment: Could SteveM's answer help you further?

Answer (score 2):

Derive your view class from `dexterity.DisplayForm`.

This may make your copy/pasted template work immediately by giving it the view methods and properties it needs. It will also make available variable like `view.widgets`, which contains a list of display widgets in schema order.

See http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.dexterity/custom-views.html#display-forms for details.

Comment: That link is broken and there doesn't seem to be a doc containing "dexterity.DisplayForm"

Comment: https://5.docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/custom-views.html - current link to docs.